# Google Hangouts - resize

Tags: google-hangouts

I installed and am using Google Hangouts on 14.04 Desktop. It works fine, but then I moved it up against the side and it did that thing where it docks to a certain size. I can't figure out how to get it to revert back to the previous size.

Has anyone resolved this issue? It's kind of annoying and I figure there is some command line way to identify the window and resize since the typical handles don't exist.

Comment: you have install hangout chrome app ?

Comment: yes, the chrome app. Sorry, I didn't specify. It integrates sufficiently that I forget that it is a chrome app.

Comment: was this the little square, or a chat window, if a chat window grab the title bar and move the window, or hit the diagonal arrow in the top righthand corner.

Comment: Once it docked, I was unable to drag it anywhere as the title bar and icons Mateo_ refers to were gone. Restarting Chrome appears to have reset it, but I'd call that a work around, not a solution.

Answer (score 3):

bring hangout to foreground then press Alt+Space then a menu will pop out, choose resize and you will be able to resize it by moving mouse